# How is maximum number of affixes affected by difficulty / act / iLvl?

Tags: diablo-iii

Today I was farming Act II on normal difficulty with 250% magic find bonus trying to find some decent rares. Of 25-30 rare items that I found **all** armor items had 4 affixes and weapons had 4 to 5 affixes.

I know that items can have up to 6 affixes ([source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/equipment#magic-find)), but apparently on lower levels the limit is 4 or possibly 5. I would like to know on what exactly maximum number of affixes depends (is it act and difficulty? Or iLvl?) and what is the earlies point in game where I can start getting items with all 6 affixes. Is there any official (or unofficial) info on that?

Also, I suspect that there is a minimum number of affixes for specific iLvl as well (have you ever seen rare item of 62 level with just one affix?). Any information on this will be appreciated as well.

Comment: As I've got 6 affix drops on Act 1, fairly sure your 'limit' assertion is wrong.

Comment: Where are you getting the information that lower levels have affix limits?  And rares, *specifically* have at least four affixes.  That's *why* they're rare.  I would suspect that any rares, period, can have 6 affixes.

Comment: Just saw you mentioned Normal - I was referring to A1 Inferno, hmm don't really have any data points from Normal :(

Comment: @fbueckert: as I mentioned, I did a run on Act 2 Normal with MF ~250% (which is pretty high and *should* give me more items with 5 or 6 affixes), and of roughly 25 rares that I picked up all had 4 affixes and that's it. I know that this dataset is tiny and I will try again, but it's enough to give the first impression

Comment: @fbueckert: also, the link that I put in my question contradicts with your assumption about 4 being the minimum. Where did you get this information, is there a source of any kind?

Comment: Huh.  I think Blizzard messed up there.  Tell me, have you ever seen any rare that has less than four affixes?  I double-checked the auction house, and even with a max level of 20, you can still easily find rares with six affixes.

Comment: @fbueckert: admittedly, no, but you can craft one, so maybe it's possible to get one dropped, too

Comment: I double-checked every rare the Blacksmith can craft, up to Inferno gear.  *Every* single rare has at least four properties.  Either I'm blind (which is entirely possible), or you're looking at an item somewhere else.

Comment: Blizzard did mess up the item list in the MF guide.  It should read: First it checks for Legendary, then 6 property rare, 5 property rare, 4 property rare, 2 PROPERTY MAGIC, 1 PROPERTY MAGIC, otherwise normal.  It is impossible to make or find a Rare (yellow item) with less than 4 modifiers.  If it is blue, then it is Magical and has 1-2 properties (note that it could look like a blue item had 4 properties because there are certain Affixes that give a bonus to 2 stats).

Comment: @DiabloMonkey I guess you are right